# Methods to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have a feel this will be a duplicate question. I have had a look around and couldn't find it, so please advise if so.

Here I wish to address the definite integral:

\begin{equation}
 I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx
\end{equation}

I have solved it using Feynman's Trick, however I feel it's limited and am hoping to find other methods to solve. Without using Residues, what are some other approaches to this integral?

My method:

\begin{equation}
 I(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-tx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx
\end{equation}

Here $I = I(1)$ and $I(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Take the derivative under the curve with respect to '$t$' to achieve:

\begin{align}
 I'(t) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-x^2e^{-tx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{-tx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx \\
&= -\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^2 + 1 - 1\right)e^{-tx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx \right] \\
&= -\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2}\:dx  + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-tx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx \\
&= -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} + I(t)
\end{align}

And so we arrive at the differential equation:

\begin{equation}
 I'(t) - I(t) = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{equation}

Which yields the solution:

\begin{equation}
 I(t) = \frac{\pi}{2}e^t\operatorname{erfc}\left(t\right)
\end{equation}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
 I = I(1) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx =  \frac{\pi}{2}e\operatorname{erfc}(1)
\end{equation}

Addendum:

Using the exact method I've employed, you can extend the above integral into a more genealised form:

\begin{equation}
 I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-kx^2}}{x^2 + 1}\:dx =  \frac{\pi}{2}e^k\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{k})
\end{equation}

Addendum 2:
Whilst we are genealising:
\begin{equation}
 I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-kx^2}}{ax^2 + b}\:dx =  \frac{\pi}{2b}e^\Phi\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{\Phi})
\end{equation}

Where $\Phi = \frac{kb}{a}$ and $a,b,k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Comment: something is wrong. $I<\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}=\sqrt\pi/2$. Your answer is greater than this value

Comment: @Andrei - You are indeed correct, I mistyped. It should be $\operatorname{efrc}$ not $\operatorname{erf}$. Thank you for the pickup.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Plancherel's theorem. Note that
$$
2I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + 1}dx.
$$Let $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Then we have
$$
\widehat{f}(\xi) = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2},
$$ and
$$
\widehat{g}(\xi) = \pi e^{-2\pi|\xi|}.
$$ By Plancherel's theorem, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{f}(\xi)\widehat{g}(\xi)d\xi\\&=&\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2-2\pi|\xi|}d\xi\\
&=&2\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2-2\pi\xi}d\xi\\
&=&2\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}e\int_{\frac{1}{\pi}}^{\infty}e^{-\pi^2\xi^2}d\xi\\
&=&2\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}e\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\xi^2}d\xi = \pi e \operatorname{erfc}(1).
\end{eqnarray}$$
This gives $I = \frac{\pi}{2}e \operatorname{erfc}(1).$

Comment: Thanks @Song! I was not aware of Plancherel's theorem :-)

Comment: With respect (as I loved the solution), but if I apply Plancherel's theorem - am I not using residues in disguise? (again, love the solution).

Comment: Your concern is legitimate. Perhaps the quickest way to evaluate $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$ is to use complex analysis tools. But the method is still real analytic. We can evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{zx}e^{-x^2}dx,\;z\in\mathbb{C}$ easily using power series expansion. About $\widehat{g}$, note that Fourier transform admits the inversion formula. So what we should check is only whether $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\widehat{g}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i\xi x}d\xi=g(x)$, and it can be checked directly by evaluating the integral separately on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a method that employs the old trick of converting the integral into a double integral.

Observe that
$$\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \int_0^\infty e^{-u(1 + x^2)} \, du.$$
So your integral can be rewritten as
$$I = \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-u(1 + x^2)} \, du \, dx.$$
or
$$I =  \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \int_0^\infty e^{-(1 + u)x^2} \, dx \, du,$$
on changing the order of integration.

Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x/\sqrt{1 + u}$ gives
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{1 + u}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{1 + u}} \, du.$$

Next exforcing a substitution of $u \mapsto u^2 - 1$ gives
$$I = \sqrt{\pi} e \int_1^\infty e^{-u^2} \, du = \sqrt{\pi} e \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \text{erfc} (1) = \frac{\pi e}{2} \text{erfc} (1),$$
as expected.

Comment: Love it. Still developing my skills with respect to integral ‘expansions’.

Comment: Is another one of those good techniques to have handy in the integration toolbox.

Comment: Absolutely. Great technique.

Comment: (+1) Nice approach, but I believe the result should actually be $\frac{\pi e}{2}\color{red}{\mathrm{erfc}}(1)=\frac{\pi e}{2}(1-\mathrm{erf}(1))$ (it's just the last line).

Comment: @projectilemotion - Indeed and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { Let } I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\left(x^2+1\right) a}}{x^2+1} d x, \textrm{ then } \\
I^{\prime}(a)&=-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x^2+1\right) a} d x \\
&=-e^{-a} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} d x \\
&=-\frac{e^{-a}}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \\
I(1)-I(0)&=-\int_0^1 e^{-a} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} d a \\
I(1)-\frac{\pi}{2}  &=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-a}}{\sqrt{a}} d a \\
&=-\sqrt{\pi} \int_0^1 e^{-(\sqrt{a})^2} d(\sqrt{a})  \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}(1) \\
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1} d x&=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\operatorname{erf}(1)) \\
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2+1} d x&=\frac{e\pi}{2} \operatorname{erfc} (1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Clever indeed $(x^2+1)a$...