# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t \tan^{-1}(t) \exp (-t^2)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

I would like to obtain
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t \tan^{-1}(t) \exp (-t^2)\,dt
$$
My idea is to use **Fourier transform** and go with **generalized Parseval**. I choose $x_{1}(t)=\tan^{-1}(t)$ and $x_{2}^{*}(t)=t \exp(-t^2)$. I don't know how to proceed after.
My problem with my idea is that I don't know the Fourier transform of the reciprocal function of tan(t).
Any suggestion??

Or maybe another choice of functions for the Generalized Parseval theorem?

Comment: After integration by parts, you arrive at [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3042183).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do integration by parts first and *then* employ Fourier transform techniques.

$$\int \arctan(x)xe^{-x^2}\,dx = -\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x)e^{-x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$

Evaluating at $\pm\infty$, the first term on the left hand side will go to $0$ since $\arctan$ is bounded and $e^{-x^2}$ converges to $0$ at infinity. The latter term is very amenable to Fourier transform techniques via Parseval. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Right after this step, I suggest we go with generalized Parseval and some small transformations can lead us to the result. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep! That will do it.